# JS error for d3-brush in d3 v4 implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

This sample worked fine for d3 v3 version. Its a trimmed version of [this sample](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/5c136de85de1c2abb6fc) where on interaction with the buttons the brush gets animated in its new position.

I am actually trying to do [this](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/5c136de85de1c2abb6fc) using d3 v4 version.

The trimming is done to identify the area of concern. The trimmed code is

```js
var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40 },
      margin2 = { top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
      x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
      y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

  var brush = d3.brushX(x2)
    .on("brush end", brushed);

  var area1 = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var area2 = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });



  // make some buttons to drive our zoom
  d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id","btnDiv")
    .style('font-size','75%')
    .style("width","250px")
    .style("position","absolute")
    .style("left","5%")
    .style("top","200px")

  var btns = d3.select("#btnDiv").selectAll("button").data([2001, 2002, 2003, 2004])

  btns = btns.enter().append("button").style("display","inline-block")

  // fill the buttons with the year from the data assigned to them
  btns.each(function (d) {
    this.innerText = d;
  })

  btns.on("click", drawBrush);

  function drawBrush() {
    // define our brush extent to be begin and end of the year
    brush.extent([new Date(this.innerText + '-01-01'), new Date(this.innerText + '-12-31')])

    // now draw the brush to match our extent
    // use transition to slow it down so we can see what is happening
    // remove transition so just d3.select(".brush") to just draw
    brush(d3.select(".brush").transition());

    // now fire the brushstart, brushmove, and brushend events
    // remove transition so just d3.select(".brush") to just draw
    brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition().delay(1000))
  }


  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var context = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "context")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());


    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("height", height2 + 7);
  });

  function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  }

  function type(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.price = +d.price;
    return d;
  }
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/162/) for correct error. The error is different when attached in the snippet**

Any help is highly appreciable.

Update:
The error is

> d3.v4.js:12632 Uncaught TypeError: group.property is not a function

Does anyone have a hunch whats the new API to resolve the error on clicking the buttons in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/162/) It would be awesome if one can update a fiddle for it. Or just atleast let me know of the modified APIs because the samples worked fine for v3.

Comment: Downvote ??? Please let me know if I ask the wrong question or is it the wrong platform to ask so?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error message, perhaps you found a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error following said example and found your question. Since your fiddle isn't quite working (unable to access the CSV), I can't confirm if my answer would work for you. But it worked locally for me.

It is made incredibly easy on v4. Simply call [brush.move(group, selection)](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_move) to programmatically move the brush selection. However, the parameter `selection` seems to be relative coordinates based on brush extent, so if your axis is date/time, you may have to convert the date into coordinate numbers.

For example, I passed in an argument for extent while defining the brush.

```
let width  = 200;
let height = 80;
let x      = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
let brush  = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());
```

Then I modified the drawBrush() function to use only brush.move():

```
function drawBrush() {
    // Convert your dates to pixels along the brush's width.
    let start = x(new Date(this.innerText + '-01-01'));
    let end   = x(new Date(this.innerText + '-12-31'));

    // Alternatively, let's say the coordinates of your year is from 20% to 40% of your graph.
    // let start = 0.2 * width;
    // let end   = 0.4 * width;

    brush.move(context.select("g.brush").transition().delay(1000).duration(500), [start, end]);
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution will break the two-step transition of the drawBrush() function, and combine it into one animation. You have to make other modifications on your own.